# <router-view> components inside other <router-view>s (same component)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I currently have the following problem with nested `<router-view>`s in my app and I want to know if this is even the right way to do it.

I have a `navigation.vue` route component with child routes configured in the router.
In this component, I have multiple `<router-view>`s (in a v-for loop).

Every router-view has its own link and if you click on it, the clicked container which holds the router-view will start a transition and reveal the content (the `page.vue` component).
To fire the transition before confirming the navigation, I listen for the `beforeRouteUpdate()` hook.

However, I now want to add other `navigation` components inside this navigation, so that I have something like that:

```html
<navigation>
    <page/>
    <page/>
    <navigation>
        <page/>
        <page/>
    </navigation>
    <page/>
</navigation>
```

The hook to open the sub-navigation seems to work - but if I try to open a page on the second level, the navigation component can't get the `$refs` that belong to itself. I see the `beforeRouteUpdate()` hook of the first level navigation being called. I think that's to be expected because it's still in the background, holding the second level navigation and its pages.

What can I do to only use the functionality of the second level navigation when it's opened?
Should I make some checks in the `beforeRouteUpdate()` hook, and are they both fired?
I'm probably confused because I don't know if the component is being reused or something - in my understanding it should be a second instance of the component.

I'm also using `<keep-alive>` around the `<router-view>`s - so if that's a problem and things work differently with that, I'd also be glad to get a hint.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way:

Both `beforeRouteUpdate()` hooks are called, so I had to make sure which of the existing navigations should do the work. The upper level navigations skip the hook.

I also needed some checks to only render the navigation in the `<router-view>` if it is in the `$route.match` array of the current route.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if this will fix your problem but in [this vue school video](https://vueschool.io/lessons/how-to-rerender-components-when-vue-router-params-changes) they talk about the Vue Router not always picking up on changes if the same component is being used. You can handle it by adding a key to the router-view like `<router-view :key=“$route.path” />`. Then any change to the path will trigger a reload of the component. Maybe you can experiment with adding keys to your nested `<router-view>`s?

Comment: Thanks! Yes I already tried to key them but I didn't see any difference, e.g. in the Vue devtools. They already have keys there (transition-x-...), I think because they are wrapped in <transition> and <keep-alive> components. But I'll check that further.